# PHP generate random number without a certain prefix?

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a random 9 character long integer.

I also want to make sure the first 3 digits aren't 814.

This is what I came up with so far:

 Function to generate number:

```
public function randnum(){
$random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,9);
return $random
}
```

Where I want to get the number at.

```
$random;
while ((substr(randnum(),0,3)) == '814'){
$random=substr(randnum(),0,3));
}
```

Is this the right way to ensure the number I get does not start with 814?

Comment: Why do you not want it to start with 814? You are removing randomness with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do {
    $random = mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
} while (strpos($random, '814') === 0);
```

Comment: This rules out all numbers starting with a zero. Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: @Jon, actually I would prefer to allow zeros too.

Comment: if I change it to `mt_rand(000000000, 999999999);` would that be interpreted as just one zero or require 9 digits still?

Comment: I am.... running a for loop using that to echo numbers....still havent gotten one starting with 0 yet. Don't know if its because it's random or it doesnt allow for it. Haha.

Comment: Well, the real test would be if all of your random number are 9 digits long. If not, then you can assume that those parameters produce non-9-digit numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It's a reasonable way to get a number that does not start with 814, but not a reasonable way to get a *random* number. You shouldn't get `time()` involved at all, and you should use `mt_rand` instead of `rand`.

You could do it better like this:

```
do {
    $random = sprintf("%09d", mt_rand(0, 999999999));
} while (substr($random, 0, 3) == "814");
```

If you don't care about the distribution of the generated random numbers (i.e. you are OK with the number being just *unpredictable* and not really *random*) and you are going to be generating lots of these, it might make sense to optimize a little:

```
do {
    $random = sprintf("%03d", mt_rand(0, 999));
} while $random == "814";

$random = $random.sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(0, 999999));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use preg_match func:

```
preg_match("/[^814]/", $str);
```

Or use

```
str_replace("814", "", $str);
```

Or use

preg_replace("/^814/", "", $str);

Comment: all slower than substr() or strpos()

Comment: It's best to avoid regex functions when regular string comparison functions will work (the former are much slower).